# Store file with or without file extension web server

Tags: php, file-upload, storage

What is the best practice for storing uploaded files on a web server. With or without the extension, or does it matter? 
We store files as a MD5 hash and linked to a database with names etc.
But should you append the file extension as well?

I know one reason is it might be easier to handle the files directly, but does it have any Pros to Not appen extension?

Regards
Daniel

Comment: this is my question too . if anyone knows the answer please reply